# Snowflake does not work on M1 Macbook Pro "Can't open lib". Any solution or update?

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apple-m1

I try to get Snowflake running on my M1 Macbook Pro, but whatever I do I get the same error message. I have found different questions related to this here, but many of them are a bit old and no one has a verified answer.

```
isql -v Snowflake
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I saw that in one thread there was mentioned that Snowflake didn't support M1 Mac yet.

1. Is this true?
2. And does anyone know when this will be supported?
3. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake ODBC driver is not yet supported for M1 or ARM-based architecture.
There is a plan to add support for these, but there is no estimation yet as of now when it will be available.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But that is of course very unfortunate. Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: For ODBC I don't know a workaround. Do you have a requirement to use only ODBC or you can use another programmatic way like using JDBC driver?

Comment: Yes, I have to use ODBC it seems like.

Comment: Snowflake should introduce m1 version asap. Its so annoying, I have to use windows machine for snowflake work :(

Comment: @SajeelHassan We've already introduced the ODBC for M1, not sure if you've seen it but it's there, see this [link](https://developers.snowflake.com/odbc/).

Comment: @Sergiu 
yeah I installed the arm64 version but still
the problem is with snowflake-connector-python and its only happening on my m1 machine. intel mac and windows work fine
--------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python

Comment: @SajeelHassan The post was about ODBC, was is the relation with Python connector here?